# Scala For Loop, If Statements

Tags: scala, if-statement, for-loop

Can you recommend a better way to do this?

```
val args = "The file on life was now won by the person who saw how to explore."

val argsSeq: Seq[String] = args.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]", "").toLowerCase.split(" ").sorted

for(i <- 0 until argsSeq.length){
  for(j <- 0 until argsSeq.length){
    if((argsSeq(i).toCharArray.sorted.deep == argsSeq(j).toCharArray.sorted.deep)) {
      if((argsSeq(i).toCharArray.deep != argsSeq(j).toCharArray.deep))
      {
        println(argsSeq(i) + " " + argsSeq(j))
      }
    }
  }     
}
```

file life

how who

life file

now won

saw was

was saw

who how

won now

First, remove the duplicate anagram pairs.

Second, alternative to the for ... for ... if ... if structure?

Thank you.

Comment: why caps? also explain what you intend to do, don't just throw code

also, take a look at for comprehension http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html

more: why not join both if clauses into a single AND clause?

Comment: Thanks, I replaced the second if ... if with &&.  Still wondering if their is a better pattern to replace the for ... for?  And best way to remove the duplicate pairs like file/life and life/file.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a short version using for-*comprehensions* (which are not equivalent to for loops, and are actually common in Scala):

```
for {
  a <- argsSeq
  b <- argsSeq.dropWhile(_ != a) if a != b && a.sorted == b.sorted
} yield println(s"$a $b")
```

Which prints:

```
file life
how who
now won
saw was
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "for loops", but if it is what OP wrote, they are actually equivalent.

Comment: for (
  a <- argsSeq
  b <- argsSeq.dropWhile(_ != a) 
  if a != b && a.sorted == b.sorted
) yield println(s"$a $b")
<console>:4: error: ')' expected but '<-' found.
         b <- argsSeq.dropWhile(_ != a) 
           ^
<console>:5: error: '(' expected but identifier found.
         if a != b && a.sorted == b.sorted

Comment: Based on what I see at the below link, I changed the curly brackets {} to ().   That cured one error, but I still get the above errors. http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/sequence-comprehensions.html

Comment: Resolved -  Not sure why, but when I put the code from Tzach on one line this resolved the errors that I note above.

Answer (score 0):

```
val args = "The file on life was now won by the person who saw how to explore."
val argsSeq: Array[String] = args.replaceAll("[^1-zA-Z0-9\\s]", "").toLowerCase().split(" ").sorted

val argsSeq_1 = argsSeq.map ( x => (x.toCharArray().sorted.deep, x) ).toList
val argsSeq_2 = argsSeq_1.groupBy(_._1)
val argsSeq_3 = argsSeq_2.map(x => x._2).filter(x=> x.length == 2).map(x => x(0)._2 + "," + x(1)._2)

println(argsSeq_1)
println(argsSeq_2)
println(argsSeq_3)
```

As we all know that functional programming paradigm in scala, usually for loop should not be used in scala because it is in imperative way.

I am also new in scala. I think you can make a list of key-value pairs that is (array of word)-word and group by key(array of word). Then extract two words in the list and generate a new list.

Sorry my answer seems no very clear because english is not my first language. You can use 3 println() statements to see my thought.

At last, argsSeq_3 is List(now,won, the,the, file,life, saw,was, how,who).

Comment: Nice work Frankie.  I like your point about getting rid of for loop because it is iterative; functional would be better.  The result must be as I show above (not your argsSeq_3) except with repeat pairs removed.

Comment: @user3439308 oh there is a tuple (the the) in my result. Just add an additional filter for val argsSeq_3. Modify last to "val argsSeq_3 = argsSeq_2.map(x => x._2).filter(x=> x.length == 2).map(x => (x(0)._2, x(1)._2)).filter(x => x._1 != x._2)", and you can get the correct result.

Comment: Nice!  I am going to work on how to remove "the,the" since I am looking only for anagram pairs, but thanks for replacing the for with map.

Comment: @user3439308 happy to see it helps